# SQL - comparing difference in sales across dates on a table

Tags: mysql

I had an interview question that kind of went like this. I had a table that contained daily sales for two items (item1 and item2) and was structured like this:

```
date       | item      | amount
01-01-2018 | item1     | 25
01-01-2018 | item2     | 30
02-01-2018 | item1     | 10
02-01-2018 | item2     | 3
```

Basically I needed to calculate the difference in sales between item1 and item2 daily and get an output table:

```
date       | amount
01-01-2018 |   -5
02-01-2018 |    7
```

Any idea on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self-join:

```
SELECT a.date, a.amount - b.amount
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   mytable b ON a.date = b.date AND a.item = 'item1' AND b.item = 'item2'
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb9f7/6 I tried it here, but I am not sure why it just gives me 0s

Comment: @Macterror you're missing the critical part of having a condition on the `item` column. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb9f7/10/0 which adjusts my solution to the column and table names you have in your fiddle

Comment: thanks, for whatever reason I wanted to join on both date and item fields but I guess only date was necessary afterall